# Ayuda con procedimiento almacenado, realizar actualización en dos tablas e insertar datos en otra

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me pueden ayudar a modificar un procedimiento almacenado, necesito que este me inserte datos en una tabla llamada `Transaccion`, obteniendo cierta información desde una tabla llamada `Clientes` y otros datos son ingresados por el usuario.

Así mismo necesito actualizar información del campo `SALDO` en la tabla `Clientes`, la inserción de los datos en la tabla `Transaccion` funciona bien, pero la actualización de datos en el campo `SALDO` de la tabla `Clientes` no, solo me los actualiza la primera vez que lo ejecuto, luego no vuelve a realizar la actualización.

Este es el procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Transaccion]
@IDCliente as varchar(5),
@FechaT as text,
@Concepto as text,
@Monto as money,
@Cobrador as nchar(225)

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Transacciones([ID Cliente], Cliente, [Fecha de Transacción], Concepto, 
                              [Saldo Actual], [Monto A Pagar], [Nuevo Saldo], Cobrador)  
    SELECT nc.[Cliente Id], nc.Cliente, @FechaT, @Concepto, nc.Saldo, @Monto, '0', @Cobrador FROM Clientes AS nc
    WHERE nc.[Cliente Id] = @IDCliente;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY

    UPDATE dbo.Transacciones SET [Nuevo Saldo] = [Saldo Actual] - [Monto A Pagar]
    WHERE [ID Cliente] = @IDCliente;

    UPDATE dbo.Clientes SET Saldo = nt.[Nuevo Saldo] FROM Transacciones AS nt
    WHERE [Cliente Id] = nt.[ID Cliente];

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
    GO
```

Estas son las Tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clientes](
    [Cliente Id] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Cliente] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Estatus] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Grupo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Dirección] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Teléfono movil] [float] NULL,
    [eMail] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Forma de Pago] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Pago Programado] [money] NULL,
    [Artículo] [nchar](100) NULL,
    [Fecha de venta] [text] NULL,
    [Precio] [money] NULL,
    [Prima] [money] NULL,
    [Saldo] [money] NULL,
    )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transacciones](
    [ID Cliente] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Cliente] [nchar](225) NOT NULL,
    [Fecha de Transacción] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Concepto] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Saldo Actual] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Monto A Pagar] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Nuevo Saldo] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Cobrador] [nchar](225) NOT NULL,
    )
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, Saludos.

Comment: Hay alguna condicion para realizar la actualizacion de datos? o simplemente se actualizan  y ya?

Comment: Si, en realidad se debe de realizar el pago solamente si el cliente tiene saldo pendiente, de lo contrario el pago no deberia de proceder. Pero tengo muchos problemas en bases de datos y no he podido realizar todo eso. 
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas recomendable sería agregarle un identificador(primary key) a tu tabla transacciones ya que al inicio del sp le haces un insert pero cuando haces el update, modificas todos los registros que tengan un ID Cliente, si ese cliente tiene 50 transacciones las va a modificar todas y supongo que lo que se requiere es solo modificar el registro actual por lo que tu sp y tabla podrian quedar de la siguiente manera

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Transaccion]
@IDCliente as varchar(5),
@FechaT as text,
@Concepto as text,
@Monto as money,
@Cobrador as nchar(225)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @TransaccionId INT;

INSERT INTO dbo.Transacciones
    ([ID Cliente], Cliente, [Fecha de Transacción], Concepto,
    [Saldo Actual], [Monto A Pagar], [Nuevo Saldo], Cobrador)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.TransaccionId
SELECT nc.[Cliente Id], nc.Cliente, @FechaT, @Concepto, nc.Saldo, @Monto, '0', @Cobrador
FROM Clientes AS nc
WHERE nc.[Cliente Id] = @IDCliente;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

UPDATE dbo.Transacciones SET [Nuevo Saldo] = [Saldo Actual] - [Monto A Pagar]
WHERE [TransaccionId] = @TransaccionId 
    AND [ID Cliente] = @IDCliente;

UPDATE dbo.Clientes SET Saldo = nt.[Nuevo Saldo] 
FROM Transacciones AS nt
WHERE nt.[TransaccionId] = @TransaccionId
    AND [Cliente Id] = nt.[ID Cliente];

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    , ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    , ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    , ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transacciones](
[TransaccionId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[ID Cliente] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[Cliente] [nchar](225) NOT NULL,
[Fecha de Transacción] [text] NOT NULL,
[Concepto] [text] NOT NULL,
[Saldo Actual] [money] NOT NULL,
[Monto A Pagar] [money] NOT NULL,
[Nuevo Saldo] [money] NOT NULL,
[Cobrador] [nchar](225) NOT NULL,
)
```